# It says I have changes not staged for commit but I literally pull the content and it says that I'm already up to date

Tags: r, git, github

I am a part of an organization (college programming class) on Github.

I have my personal repo and also my class repo within that organization.

I do not have permission to edit any files from my class repo, rather I am supposed to clone both repos locally onto my computer and then copy files from my localized class repo to my localized personal repo in order to do homework and such.

I always pull from my remote class repo to my local class repo and it says that I am already up to date, but when I check the status it says that I have changes not staged for commit.

I don't understand how this is possible when I do not have any way of changing anything because I literally do not have permission.
What could I do in order for it say that my working tree is clean?

[image]

Comment: you have deleted some files locally where you have permissions. Try doing `git reset --hard` to go back to the most recent pull, and reread your course notes :)

Comment: When you checkout files from a repo, you make copies on your local machine. you can do whatever you want to those files. You just don't have permission to push those changes back to github. But you certainly can (and apparently have) made changes inside those directories. It seems the problem is that you are using an icloud drive and probably have "optimize" storage on so your OS is moving files for you. See here for how to turn that off: https://www.sync.com/help/why-do-my-files-have-an-icloud-extension/

Comment: I turned off the option to optimize my storage. I deleted my local repos and then copied them again onto my machine but the same message is still there

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned here](https://faq.pdfviewer.io/en/articles/3914738-unable-to-open-files-with-pdf-icloud-extension#:%7E:text=Apple%20uses%20the%20%22.,you%20double%2Dclick%20to%20open.), Apple uses the "`.icloud`" extension to indicate that files are not yet downloaded to your Mac, but available through iCloud Drive.
Finder automatically downloads these files on-demand when you double-click to open.

It is possible you (or someone else habilitated to commit) previously added, as part of a `git add`+`git commit`, those temporary files, but later on accessed those files (the actual ones), which would trigger the deletion of those pointers.

I would recommend adding (or asking for) the rule "`*.icloud`" to the `.gitignore` file of your repository.

Comment: And how exactly would I go about doing that? I do not have a .gitignore file in my localized class repo

Comment: @user901871 You could simply create one, in which you add this rule: `echo *.icloud > .gitignore`